# TargetInvocationException with CSharpCodeProvider generated DLLs

Tags: c#, scripting

I am attempting to create a scripting system which uses C#'s CSharpCodeProvider to build C# code at run-time. This is for a simple game engine I am working on, written in XNA 4.0. 
The goal is to have users be able to modify gameplay elements through C# without having access to the nuts and bolts of the game engine (Rendering code, physics code, networking, etc). The scripts are compiled at runtime into DLLs by the engine. At the moment I have communication between the engine and the compiled script DLL established. (I created a Player.cs script, and after compilation it was able to call my engine's "Engine.Print("Foobar"); method from the script DLL) The engine is also able to use the Script's methods (The engine searches through all new Classes defined in script after compilation, and calls their "OnCompile()" method after compilation.

The problem starts with inter-script communication: I have 2 scripts, Inventory and Player:

Inventory.cs:

```
public class Inventory  
{  
    int foobar;  

    public Inventory()
    {
        foobar = 42;
    }

    public static void OnCompile()
    {
        // This method exists in the Engine DLL, linked to this script
        Engine.Print("OnCompile Inventory");     
    }
}
```

Player.cs:

```
using Scripts.Inventory;

public class Player
{
    Inventory inventory;  

    public Player()  
    {
        //inventory = new Inventory();  
        Engine.Print("Player created");  
    }


    public static void OnCompile()  
    {
        Engine.Print("OnCompile Player");  
        Player test = new Player();
    }
}
```

This code functions, debug output prints:

OnCompile Inventory
OnCompile Player
Player created

However, once I uncomment the inventory = new Inventory(); in the Player constructor
Debug output looks like:

OnCompile Inventory
OnCompile Player

Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Inventory.cs, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Scripts.Player.Player..ctor()
   at Scripts.Player.Player.OnCompile()

I have ensured my Player.cs.dll has a reference to Inventory.cs.dll. My compilation code is as follows:

```
    public static bool Compile(string fileName, bool forceRecompile = false)
    {
        // Check to see if this assembly already exists.
        // If it does, then just return a reference to it, unless
        // it is told to forceRecompile, in which case
        // it will delete the old, and continue compiling
        if (File.Exists("./" + fileName + ".dll"))
        {
            if (forceRecompile)
            {
                File.Delete(fileName + ".dll");
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }


        // Generate a name space name. this means removing the initial ./
        // of the path, and replacing all subsequent /'s with .'s
        // Also removing the .cs at the end

        // i.e: ./Scripts/Player.cs becomes
        //      Scripts.Player

        string namespaceName = "";

        if (fileName.LastIndexOf('.') != -1)
        {
            fileName = fileName.Remove(fileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
        }

        namespaceName = fileName.Replace('/', '.');
        namespaceName = namespaceName.Substring(2);

        // Add references, starting with ScriptBase.dll.
        // ScriptBase.dll is a helper library that provides
        // access to debug functions such as Console.Write

        List<string> references = new List<string>() 
        { 
            "./ScriptBase.dll",
            "System.dll"        // TODO: remove later
        };


        // Open the script file wit ha StreamReader
        StreamReader fileStream;
        string scriptSource = "";

        fileStream = File.OpenText("./" + fileName + ".cs");


        // Preprocess the script. This is important, as it resolves
        // using statements, so that if a script references another
        // script, it will have the dependency registered before
        // compiling.
        do
        {
            string line = fileStream.ReadLine();

            string[] words = line.Split(' ');

            // Found a using statement:
            if (words[0] == "using")
            {
                // Get the namepsace name:
                string library = words[1];

                library = library.Remove(library.Length - 1); // get rid of semicolon

                // Convert back to a path
                library = library.Replace('.', '/');


                // See if the assembly exists, or we are forcing the recompilation
                if (!File.Exists("./" + library + ".cs.dll") || forceRecompile)
                {
                    // We need to compile it now.
                    // See if the script file exists...
                    if (File.Exists("./" + library + ".cs"))
                    {
                        // if it does, compile that, if it doesn't then we bail
                        if (!Compile("./" + library + ".cs", forceRecompile))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                // Now that it's compiled, and we need it link it with our reference list...
                references.Add("./" + library + ".cs.dll");
            }
            // Piece it back together as one string, line by line.
            scriptSource = scriptSource + line + "\n";

        } while (!fileStream.EndOfStream);


        fileStream.Close();

        // Automagically add our namepsace to the script, so the scriptor doesn't have to, also automatically
        // include ScriptBase
        // This is where Engine class is found for Print() debug method        

        string source = "using ScriptBase; namespace " + namespaceName + "{" + scriptSource + "}";


        // Set up the compiler:
        Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string> 
        { 
            { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } 
        };

        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);


        // Create compilation params... Here we link our references, and append ".cs.dll" to our file name
        // So now for example, ./Scripts/Player.cs compiles to ./Script/Player.cs.dll
        CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters(references.ToArray(), fileName + ".cs.dll")
        {
            GenerateInMemory = true,
            GenerateExecutable = false, // compile as DLL

        };

        // Compile and check errors
        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);
        if (results.Errors.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
            {
                // Write out any errors found:
                Console.WriteLine("Syntax Error in " + error.FileName + " (" + error.Line + "): " + error.ErrorText);
            }

            return false;
        }

        // Return our Script struct, which keeps all the information together,
        // and registers it so that Script.GetCompiledScript("./Scripts/Player.cs.dll");
        // returns the compiled script, or null if it's never been compiled

        Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName + ".cs.dll");

        foreach (Type type in results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes())
        {
            new ScriptClass(fileName + ".cs.dll", type);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I have stepped through the code, and Inventory.cs is always getting compiled before Player.cs as intended, and it is properly adding Inventory.cs.dll to the references list  of Player.cs before compiling.

I must be missing something, simply linking the DLLs in the reference list does not seem to be sufficient, the error mentions the file Inventory.cs is not found. Where do I specify the path to search for the source .cs? (The .cs.dll compiled script is always found in the same path as the .cs source script)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add handler for the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event. In the handler you can map the assembly names to the assemblies that you have loaded with `Assembly.LoadFrom()`.

The assemblies loaded with `Assembly.LoadFrom()` belong to so called loadfrom context. Normal referenced assemblies and assemblies loaded with `Assembly.Load()` belong to load context. Assemblies do not find automatically referenced assemblies that exist in other contexts.

In this case both dynamically compiled assemblies are loaded into loadfrom context and so they should be able too each other. However, the executing assembly exists in load context and so it cannot see the other assemblies in loadfrom context. The `results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes()` forces the assemblies to be loaded into load context and the exception is thrown because the assembly reference cannot be resolved. The `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event needs to be used to bind the assemblies from another binding context.

More about binding contexts: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx